# I'm new to proving inequalities. How does one prove this?

Tags: inequality, a.m.-g.m.-inequality

If a, b, and c are non-negative real numbers and $a + b + c = 2 $, prove that 
$ 2 \ge a^2 b^2 + b^2 c^2 + c^2 a^2 $

Comment: Perhaps you can consider Vieta's formulas

Answer (score 3):

It's actually $1\ge a^2 b^2 + b^2 c^2 + c^2 a^2$.

It is enough to show the homogenous
symmetric inequality
$$ (a+b+c)^4 - 16(a^2 b^2 + b^2 c^2 + c^2 a^2)\ge 0$$

Assume an ordering $a \le b \le c$. Write 
\begin{eqnarray}
a &=&p \\
b&=& p+ q\\
c &=& p+q +r
\end{eqnarray}
with $p$, $q$, $r\ge 0$. Substitute $a$, $b$, $c$ in terms of $p$, $q$, $r$ in the expression above. We get a polynomial of degree $4$ in $p$, $q$, $r$ with all the coefficients positive. Since $p$, $q$, $r$ are also positive we conclude that the expression is positive.

Obs: We have equality if and only if two of the $a$, $b$, $c$ are equal and the third is $0$.

Answer (score 0):

We'll prove that
$$(a+b+c)^4\geq16(a^2b^2+a^2c^2+b^2c^2).$$
Indeed, by AM-GM we obtain:
$$(a+b+c)^4=((a^2+b^2+c^2)+2(ab+ac+bc))^2\geq$$
$$\geq\left(2\sqrt{2(a^2+b^2+c^2)(ab+ac+bc)}\right)^2=8\sum_{cyc}(a^3b+ab^3+a^2bc)\geq$$
$$\geq8\sum_{cyc}(2a^2b^2+0)=16(a^2b^2+a^2c^2+b^2c^2).$$
Done!

Comment: Nice again. A very useful proof! +1